# Aws instance created by autoscale event or not

Tags: amazon-web-services

I would like to find out if an instance is spun up manually, using a script or via an auto-scale event. I see that every instance has requesterid, can I use it? If yes, what exactly will be populated when an autoscale event spins up an instance.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by adding a tag to your auto scaling groups named something like ASGroupName. When you create the tag using the AWS Web Console you can check the *Tag New Instances* option. That will cause the tag to get propagated down to all instances created by the AS group. Now you will be able to identify AS instances on whether or not they have this tag and the value of the tag will give you the name of the AS group.

Comment: Thank You David. Sorry cannot upvote your answer dont have enough reputation points as yet.